# Excel - How to Fill Cells B, C, and D based on Cell A

Tags: database, excel, spreadsheet, autofill, auto-populate

First let me say that I've tried searching but I'm having a difficult time expressing exactly what I want to do which made searching difficult.

Essentially, I'm filling out several spread sheets with thousands of rows of information.  I have a column full of identifying numbers.  I use that number to find a name and fill in the adjacent cells.  As there are several workbooks which have a lot of overlapping information, I would like to find a way to match those numbers to names I have already found.

I am certain there is an easier way to ask this but its lost on me right now.  I appreciate any help you all may have.

Example:

Sheet 1

A-----B-----C-----D-----E
0012--James-007---Bond
0234--Max---F-----Smart
5618--M-----M-----M
2869--Q-----Q-----Q

Sheet 2

A-----B-----C-----D-----E
0011--Have to find new info
0012--How to fill out these cells using previously found info?
0234--More previously found info
1587--Must find new info

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using the [VLOOKUP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/) function on Sheet 2, finding data in the table on Sheet 1 based on the value of Column A on Sheet 2.